# Spring Cloud Gateway pass path parameters to custom filter

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway project and I am writing a custom filter. I am trying to extract the path paramters and pass them as arguments to this filter in the application properties file.

Consider the following configuration in the application properties file `application.yaml`, there is a route (with `id` `simple_route`) which has a predicate to match the path `employee/{employeeId}` where `employeeId` is some number. There is a custom filter `MyCustomFilter` which takes the `employeeId` as argument and some other arguments.

```yaml
spring:
    cloud:
        gateway:
            routes:
                - id: simple_route
                  uri: http://localhost:8080
                  predicates:
                      - Method=GET
                      - Path=/employees/{employeeId}
                  filters:
                      - MyCustomFilter=employeeId,anotherArgument
```

How can this be achieved? I have knowledge on how to pass arguments to a filter in this configuration but I don't have awareness on how to capture a segment of the path and pass that as an argument to the filter.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Cloud Gateway it is possible to directly retrieve the path params from the custom filter.
In order to do that, it is needed to create a class that implements GatewayFilter.

```
@Component
public class TestFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        Map<String, String> pathParams = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
    
        //... do your logic

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Inside this class, it is possible to retrieve the path params using the following lines of code:

```
Map<String, String> pathParams = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Inside your RouteConfig class, you can define a path with path params in this way:

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfig {

@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/auth/api/auth/{param1}/test/{param2}")
                    .filters(f -> f.filter(new TestFilter()))
                    .uri("lb://AUTH-SERVICE"))
            .build();
    }
}
```

In this case, hitting the url http://localhost:8080/auth/api/auth/signin/test/user1 will result in having the following map inside the custom filter TestFilter:

```
pathParams = {Collections$UnmodifiableMap@9086}  size = 2
 "param1" -> "signin"
 "param2" -> "user1"
```